# Cypress checking line-through

Tags: user-interface, cypress, ui-automation, ui-testing, line-through

I have a web page where the items when checked get a line-through as in the image below.

Before checking:

```js
<li style="text-decoration: none;">test</li>
```

After checking:

```js
<li style="text-decoration: line-through;">test</li>
```

[image]

I am trying to assert on the line-though with :

```js
cy.get('li').should('have.css', 'text-decoration', 'line-through')
```

But, I get this error on assertion :

```
assertexpected <li> to have CSS property text-decoration with the value line-through, but the value was line-through solid rgb(0, 0, 0)
```

How do I assert on the line-through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a partial check.

I know this works `Cypress.$(e).css('text-decoration').includes('line-through')` so perhaps this:

```js
cy.get('li')
  .invoke('css', 'text-decoration')
  .should('include', 'line-through')
```